# Highcharts enable pan without holding panKey

Tags: javascript, highcharts, react-highcharts

In js Highcharts I can enable panning by specifying a panKey and setting panning.enabled to true as specified in the [documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.panning)

```
panKey: 'ctrl',
panning: {
    enabled: true,
    type: 'x'
},
```

Is there any way to have panning enabled by default, so you can just click to pan without holding the specified panKey?

Comment: It is implemented like you described because the zoom is enabled by default and the chart must be zoomed to make panning work. Or do you have a different usecase?

Comment: Sorry I probably should have included the use case. I'm adding custom buttons for zooming, panning etc. So I'd like the user to be able to click a button to toggle zooming or panning. Ideally, if they've toggled on panning, they could just click and drag; they wouldn't have to hold a panKey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. This was really my fault for not experimenting and fully understanding the documentation. By default, zooming is not enabled, so leaving all zoom options blank will disable zooming. Then just set panning to enabled, and don't specify a panKey.

```
chart: {
    panning: {
        enabled: true,
        type: 'x'
    }
}
```